# Why when doing animations with matplotlib, frame "0" appears several times?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Take a look at this simple code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.animation as animation
    
# initializing a figure
fig = plt.figure()

# labeling the x-axis and y-axis
axis = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 1000), ylim=(0, 1000))

# lists storing x and y values
x, y = [], []

line, = axis.plot(0, 0)
    
def animate(frame_number):
    print("frame",frame_number)
    x.append(frame_number)
    y.append(frame_number)
    line.set_xdata(x)
    line.set_ydata(y)
    return line,


anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=1000,
                            interval=20, blit=True)
fig.suptitle('Straight Line plot', fontsize=14)

plt.show()
```

When running this code, I got the animation but in the terminal I got the `"frame"N` message like this:

```
 python straight_animation.py 
frame 0
frame 0
frame 0
frame 1
frame 2
frame 3
frame 4
frame 5
frame 6
```

and then when it reaches the limit , again

```
frame 999
frame 0
frame 0
frame 1
```

You can see that frame 0 appears three times in the beginning and two times after reaching the end.

Why is this happening?

It seems that in matplotlib animation frame "0" is some kind of "preparation" and the data comes after that in frame 1 but in my system I got data from frame 0 so some kind of explanation on the workings of matplotlib would be useful. I wonder if I would have to modify my frame 0 to appear as a "frame 1"

Answer (score 1):

Your `animate` function is called both to initialize the animation and to update it, i.e. twice on frame 0. A solution would be to pass an `init_func`. As per the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation.html) of `matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation`:

> **init_func : *callable, optional***
>
> A function used to draw a clear frame. If not given, the results of drawing from the first item in the frames sequence will be used. This function will be called once before the first frame.
>
> The required signature is:
>
> `def init_func() -> iterable_of_artists`
>
> If `blit == True`, init_func must return an iterable of artists to be re-drawn. This information is used by the blitting algorithm to determine which parts of the figure have to be updated. The return value is unused if blit == False and may be omitted in that case.